# Quarter 1 data more predictive of Q3 than Q2?

Tags: cross-validation

I have datasets for a sales for 3 quarters of a year: quarter 1, 2 and 3.  I'm trying to train a model to predict total quantity that will be sold.

I created a model that uses Q1 and Q2 data as training data to predict Q3 and used K-fold cross-validation.

Interestingly, if I use only Q1 data, it alone is a better predictor of quantity sold than a model trained on Q2.  There are an identical number of observations in both quarters, and that the data is complete for both quarters.

Are there any obvious factors that I'm overlooking that might explain this?

Comment: How many different time series do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to give a proper answer without seeing the data or having a deeper understanding of the problem. Some immediate thoughts that come to mind though are:

- How are you predicting the data, this to me sounds like a time series problem are you using an appropriate model ?
- Why are you predicting Q3 ? I am assuming you are testing your model prior to predicting Q4 so you can estimate the total sales.
- There could be some sort of time dependence which makes Q1 sales more like Q3 sales for example maybe there was a special event on in Q2 that skews the numbers.
- Perhaps you don't have enough data ? If you only have sales from Q1 , Q2 , Q3 for a single year and your trying to predict total sales in a quarter then you only essentially have 3 data points. This is likely to give very high variance on any estimates.